# 'no active partition found' error after install of Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I just installed the ubuntu from usb with root swap and home partition. I also set to install boot loader to the same partition with root. However I cannot boot the ubuntu after intallation and it give 'no active partition found' error. How could I solve that problem ?
Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with suse. my harddrive was formatted as GPT. I changed it to MBR and made a new partition system and it seemed to sort it out.